# Uppy showSelectedFiles not hiding files

Tags: reactjs, hide, uppy

I have this supersimple ReactJs [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/uppy-showselectedfiles-not-working-m4y4t?file=/src/App.js) can someone explain how the `showSelectedFiles: false`  works. I read the [docs](https://uppy.io/docs/dashboard/#showSelectedFiles-true) that the selected files after user have picked files is hidden but they are not in my Sandbox.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the option in as a prop to your `<Dashboard>` and not when you initialize Uppy() like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Dashboard
        uppy={this.uppy}
        plugins={["Webcam"]}
        showSelectedFiles={false}
      />
    );
  }
```